# Firebase Security - Read with ID

Tags: firebase, security, rules

I have users who can create ids with a profile attached like so:

```
profiles: {
    id_1:
        name: Bob
    id_2:
        name: Jim
}
```

Bob and Jim can sign up and input their special id provided to them. For example, Bob creates an account, with email and password, and also enters his id to see related profile info. His profile is private to him and user that created it.

When Bob signs up, how can I setup my security rules, so that before his account is created (email & password), I can check the id exists? But also keep it private, such that only those with the id can look at the data?

Let me know if I should explain differently.

Comment: Why not use the users uid from firebase?

Comment: Because another user needs to create the profile on their behalf.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the general-public unauthenticated user (before sign-up) to be able to read the UIDs, but not any of the data inside those nodes? Unfortunately that's not possible, check out [this article](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-security-rules-88d94606ce4a) which includes the sentence "*Firebase rules cascade in such a way that granting a read or write privilege to a parent node always grants that read/write access to all child nodes.*"

With that said, it isn't impossible to accomplish your end-goal... instead you would need to have an additional *publicly readable* table that lists all UIDs, and leave the personal data inside the secure `profiles` table.

As I'm sure you're aware from [the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), your database rules would then use the format:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "profiles": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "otherTable": {
        ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```